# Select formatted Date in JCR SQL2

Tags: java, jcr, jcr-sql2

I would like to execute an JCR SQL2 query, which selects me the year of a date-property. Something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT([jcr:created], '%Y') FROM x
```

Is something similar even possible= I have searched and did not find anything, but I could just suck at searching, so sorry, if something like this has been answered before.

Thanks!

Cheers,
Evan

Comment: In my eyes your query is not a valid SQL statement. The computer does need at least the FROM clausel, where the computer should finde the nodes.

Comment: @reporter You are right, it's not a valid SQL statement, it was just an example. I changed that to prevent confusion, though the problem will remain the same.

Comment: I understand you're point, and I answered your question below. But your query may be misleading to others: the 'x' in the FROM clause identifies a node type, and it's unrelated to the 'x' in the property name's that represents a namespace prefix. Using a different namespace prefix would eliminate this ambiguity: SELECT DATE_FORMAT([jcr:created], '%Y') FROM x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the JSR-283 specification outlining a way to obtain just the year (or month or day or time) of a DATE field. The only way to accomplish what you want is to get the DATE value (using either the rows or the nodes in the `javax.jcr.query.QueryResult` object) as a `java.util.Calendar` object and

If you're query is something like:

```
SELECT [jcr:created] AS dateField FROM [mix:created] ...
```

then the following example shows how to do this by using the rows:

```
javax.jcr.query.QueryResult result = query.execute();
RowIterator iter = result.getRows();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Row row = iter.nextRow();
    Value value = row.getValue("dateField");
    // Our query won't return a null, since `jcr:created' is mandatory
    // and autocreated on `mix:created`, so we don't have to check 
    // value for null. Other properties, however, may not be mandatory
    // so you might need to check null for other queries ...
    int year = value.getDate().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // do something with the year
}
```

It is important to understand that `value.getDate()` will attempt to convert the actual value to a DATE if it is not already one. This may cause an exception if the actual value can't be converted.

If the query has a single selector (e.g, a single table in the `FROM` clause), then each row in the results contains a single node, and rather than using the rows as we did above we can get a `NodeIterator`:

```
javax.jcr.query.QueryResult result = query.execute();
NodeIterator iter = result.getNodes();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Node node = iter.nextNode();
    // The 'jcr:created' property is mandatory (and autocreated), so 
    // in our case we don't have to check if the property exists
    // or handle a PathNotFoundException. And single-valued properties
    // always have a value.
    Value value = node.getProperty("jcr:created").getDate();
    int year = value.getDate().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // do something with the year
}
```

Note that we had to use the property name rather than the alias.

Comment: I was hoping, that there was another way to get the date in the right format directly from the server. I did not wanted to parse the date in Java for various reasons. But thanks for your answer!